# How should I start an electronics project?

Tags: analog, circuit-design, design

**Background**

I have limited exposure to practical and real-life electronics (particularly in the analog world). I haven't made something all by myself from the ground. So to remedy this, I want to make something.

This is what I want to build, albeit a simplified version with 4 or 6 light things to hit.
[image: Speed of light arcade game]
I am envisioning it that you have to hit the lit up things n # of times and once you hit it the nth time a time will display to show how long it took.

**Problem**

Because of my lack of experience, I am not entirely sure how to start. Should I try searching for existing designs (cursory searches didn't find anything substantial)? Should I start by designing a circuit that would behave in that way, and if so, how do I know what components to use?

**Brainstorming**

Currently these are the things I think I might need:
LEDs, Resistors, Capacitors(?), some sort of programmable circuit board (Arduino?), certainly wires, power source (batteries), 555 timer?. (i like FPGAs but they seem to expensive for something like this)

Apologies if the question is too broad. Let me know if more information is required.

Comment: Your post will get probably deleted since it is too broad. Product recommendations are off topic too but I will give this one while your post exists: A mercury micronova FPGA module is easy to use and fairly affordable. FPGAs as chips are difficult to mount wire up all the appropriate auxilliary circuitry so stay away from working with FPGAs in chip form unless you're being paid to do it or really know what you're doing and have the $$$. They're real fun to work with though. FPGAs are overkill for something like this though but would be a good learning experience.

Comment: Since this site generally doesn't like broad design questions I tried to answer in the most general way I could. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Designing something like this will take a while, and it's too much to really do through a site like this, but I can at least tell you how I would set about it:

1. Break the task into chunks, and do each in turn, and
2. Start with the important bits - in this case, it's going to be all about the interface.

There's a whole lot of mechanical stuff to sort out too, but since this is the electrical engineering stack, I'll skip that.  Then I'd break the electronics into several tasks:

1. The buttons. They need bright illumination, a switch so they can tell they've been hit, and they need to be robust.
2. Displays: one or two largeish 3-digit, 7-segment displays. These you can just buy, it's a case of looking at what's available and what you want or can afford.
3. Other lights: like the displays, build a shopping list.
4. Sound: I'm sure that's something to look at too.
5. Once you have a good idea what you want for an interface, you need to work out how to do the brains of it. A microcontroller or a microprocessor. Exactly what type will depend on what you have in the points above.  You might find, for example, that you can do everything with an Arduino or similar except the sound, in which case you might want to go back and change what you want there. Or you might decide that fully detailed stereo is important and get an ARM board instead.
6. Power. This is usually good to do last, once you know what you need to power, though again you might end up revisiting the above points to save some money or simplify things.

Then, to take an example, lets look at point 1. We can break that down again into even smaller bits. You'll need a robust frame and a semi-transparent dome, but that's not really electronics, so let's skip that for now.  It also needs a light that can be switched on and off, and a switch to tell when it's pressed.

Lets start with the light. Have a look at some lightbulbs and how bright they are. Look up their light output online, and work out how much light you need. Pick a technology - probably LED. Pick a specific light. Work out what voltage and current it needs. Check if that is too much for a microcontroller, probably it is, so you'll need a MOSFET or similar to switch it on and off, so pick one. Work out how to drive it from a generic low voltage logic signal (you'll fill in the details when you pick a microcontroller). Choose the other parts you need to make a complete circuit, such as resistors etc. Finally, check the heat dissipated by each part, and choose heatsinks as necessary.  Then move on to the next task on the list.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

1. Develop your requirements. This will be everything from the end functionality to how it's powered, to how every single component should function within the system. This gives you a set of parameters for your design as well as a rough idea of the needed modules. This is because you will be breaking down your idea into modules with which each can be designed independently but using the shared set of parameters for interoperability.
2. Work on developing the design of each module individually.
3. Build out each module individually, testing it's functionality to make sure it fits the specifications.
4. Piece all modules together for the final functioning end piece.

This is a very generic answer as it is something that is likely be to opinion based, but I believe most design paradigms focus around these basic stages. If you try to skip any part of them you'll be complicating your process due to various issues. Most beginners will attempt to skip the documentation and module steps, resulting in trying to build out a complex system in one shot, which is definitely a more difficult path. Documenting your requirements, planning, and breaking down your overall design into modules/smaller pieces is the most important aspect of a design process that scales well with increasingly complex designs.